# How do I make an object change color when it hits another object?

Tags: swift

I'm making a screen saver in swift, and the screen saver has a paddle, and a ball, like pong. I am trying to make it so that when the ball hits the paddle, both the paddle and the ball change to a random color. How would I accomplish this?

It is curently set to fill in white.

```
 private func drawBall() {
    let ballRect = NSRect(x: ballPosition.x - ballRadius,
                          y: ballPosition.y - ballRadius,
                          width: ballRadius * 2,
                          height: ballRadius * 2)
    let ball = NSBezierPath(roundedRect: ballRect,
                            xRadius: ballRadius,
                            yRadius: ballRadius)
    NSColor.white.setFill()
    ball.fill()
}

private func drawPaddle() {
    let paddleRect = NSRect(x: paddlePosition - paddleSize.width / 2,
                            y: paddleBottomOffset - paddleSize.height / 2,
                            width: paddleSize.width,
                            height: paddleSize.height)
    let paddle = NSBezierPath(rect: paddleRect)
    NSColor.white.setFill()
    paddle.fill()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it seems to me that you want a Collision detector.
I suggest use iOS UIDynamic instead of implementing your own physics engine.

specifically this class UICollisionBehavior.